Scanner for Textbox causes PostBack
I have a textbox which gets information from a scanner or scanned barcode item. However, when I scan the barcode, it causes an AutoPostBack which erases all the information that has been entered. I have tried

setting AutoPostBack to false without much improvement

<asp:TextBox ID="bookISBN" runat="Server" AutoPostBack="false" OnTextChanged="bookISBN_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>

code-behind:
protected void bookISBN_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime lastKeyPress = DateTime.Now;
    string bBookISBN = string.Empty;
    while (((TimeSpan)(DateTime.Now - lastKeyPress)).TotalSeconds > 600)
    {
        bBookISBN = bookISBN.Text;
    }
}


Javascript

    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById('<%= bookISBN.ClientID %>').addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 13) { // Enter key
                e.preventDefault(); // Prevent the form from submitting
            }
        });
    </script>


I also tried using the KeyDownEventArgs but it also acted in the same manner. Is there something more that I need to do?


Change the scanner settings so it won't send a carriage return after reading the barcode.

@VDWWD change the scanner settings doesn't seem like good practice in the case that the scanner gets changed after testing

As a general rule, on any asp.net page, the FIRST button that appears in any of the markup will be clicked (triggered) when the user hits the enter key.
However, I have to assume the scanner is thus sending a "enter key" after the scan, and we probably want this to occur!
Now, a post-back on the page should not "empty" out the text box, unless we messed up the code on that page.
Remember, for any button click, or any text box event, or anything that triggers a post back?
Well, the page on-load event fires (runs) first, and THEN your code stub runs. And of course, with a "enter key" in the mix then you are probably suffering 2 page post backs. One from the text box (on change event + autopostback = true), and then one from the button on the page that follows (is later on) in the markup.
A simple fix would be to remove the auto post back (and event) from the text box, and place a button right after the text box. Now, when you scan the enter key will of course run/click the button (and our code stub for that button).
So, then place your scan code in the button stub. In other words, hitting enter key will run the button that appears anywhere in the markup. You have to be careful, since even buttons in a GridView will run, which suggests the button in the first row of the GridView will run! (if the GV appears before our text box and button).
Last but not least, do check your page load code stub, as I have often over the years by accident placed some control setup code (such as setting defaults for controls and loading up say some combo boxes). However, you only want such setup code to run on the REAL first page load, hence for the last 200 web pages I have made, I always thus have this in the page load event:
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then

        ' setup code here to load up combo box, controls and grid view

    End If

End Sub

Edit: - I missed the C# tag, so above becomes this:
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            // the real first page load code goes here
        }
    }

If  you fail to use the above Not IsPostBack check, then your page load event will fire each and every time BEFORE the button or event code stub you have. As a result, such setup and control loading code will of course overwrite any choice the user made. So, do check your page load event, and check if you have that "all important" PostBack check, since you really can't build a working web page without that "Not IsPostBack" check, which only runs on the first "real" page load.
So, you could I suppose try to introduce some JavaScript to trap the enter key, but really, it is just oh so simple to place a button that follows the textbox in your markup, and assume that will run when the user scans. Hence, remove the event and autopostback from the text box, and place that code in an asp button placed right after the text box.
Do keep in mind that any button that appears in markup from the start of the page will run (the first button in markup). Hence, I suggest that you set any (and all) buttons on the page with:
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="button top of markup"
            OnClick="Button2_Click"
            UseSubmitBehavior="false"
            />

The UseSubmitBehavour does not prevent the button from working when clicked on, but DOES prevent the enter key from triggering the button. So, if you have (need) buttons that appear before the text box (and our button we want to click/run), then you need to set them all with UsesubmitBehavour="false", since as noted, the first button in the markup without this attribute will run when Enter key is hit.
